How would you find unknown values within a given final Simplex tableau for a solved LP problem?
I’m on an MSc Data Science course and have recently learned the Simplex method, and have been doing some revision questions to boost my understanding ahead of an exam.
One of the revision questions I did stumped me a tad. The question was as follows:
The solution to the LP problem
maximise $z = 5x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3$
subject to: $2x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \le 15 $
$x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 \le 20$
$x_1 - x_2 \le 5$
$x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0$
is



$x_1$
$x_2$
$x_3$
$s_1$
$s_2$
$s_3$
$Solution$




$0$
$0$
$0$
$B$
$0$
$1$
$C$


$0$
$1$
$A$
$1/3$
$0$
$-2/3$
$5/3$


$0$
$0$
$4/3$
$-2/3$
$1$
$1/3$
$35/3$


$1$
$0$
$1/3$
$1/3$
$0$
$1/3$
$20/3$



(For clarity, the top row is the objective function row in this instance.)

What is the value of A?
What is the value of B?
What is the value of C?

When I was initially unsure of how to tackle the problem and looked at the provided solutions, no method was given and the intended answers were as follows:
$A = 1/3$
$B = 2$
$C = 35$
Now, I could work out C easily enough; to work out C, I simply looked at what variables were in the basis (and saw that these were $x_1$, $x_2$ and $s_2$ from the tableau), and substituted the relevant basic variables into the objective function as follows:
$C = (5*20/3) + (5/3) + (2*0) = 105/3 = 35 $
However, I was a lot more stumped on A and B. My initial thought for B, as it was in the $s_1$ column, was to substitute the relevant basic variables into the formula for constraint 1, as follows, and work out B by working out the shortfall between 15 and the sum of the relevant basic variables, as $s_1$ of course represents slack:
$B = 15 - (2*20/3) - (5/3) - 0 = 0 $
However, as shown, this of course equals 0 rather than 2, so this clearly wasn't right.
I also wondered whether it might have something to do with sensitivity analysis, as this is one example of an area in Simplex where you need to work with unknown values and work out their value to work out the range in which the coefficient can fall for the tableau to remain optimal, but I was unsure how to apply it here.
Does anyone have any ideas? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Start with the slack basis ${s_1,s_2,s_3}$ and perform two pivots.

Thank you for the reply. Correct me if I'm wrong, but are you essentially suggesting that I perform the full Simplex method on the given LP problem to get to the final Simplex tableau shown myself and work out the values in that manner?

Yes, that is what I am suggesting.

Is there any known way of imputing the values of A and B without manually performing the Simplex method on the original problem? Or is doing the Simplex method the only way to find the values?

You can manipulate the inverse of the basis matrix, but I don't think that is simpler here.
